# Add "Post Options" for new wordpress post

Tags: posts, admin, options

How i can add "Post Options" section under wysiwyg editor?
[**Like this**](http://themeblvd.com/demo/assets/framework/shortcode_generator.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function.

Take a look to this tutorials:

1. [Using add_meta_box()](http://andrewferguson.net/2008/09/26/using-add_meta_box/)
2. [Tutorial: Creating Custom Write Panels in WordPress](http://wefunction.com/2008/10/tutorial-creating-custom-write-panels-in-wordpress/)
3. [Example How To Add Meta Boxes To Edit Area](http://wpengineer.com/1991/example-how-to-add-meta-boxes-to-edit-area/)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code just to get you started.

```
/* Define the custom box */

// WP 3.0+
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'post_options_metabox' );

// backwards compatible
add_action( 'admin_init', 'post_options_metabox', 1 );

/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_post_options' );

/**
 *  Adds a box to the main column on the Post edit screen
 * 
 */
function post_options_metabox() {
    add_meta_box( 'post_options', __( 'Post Options' ), 'post_options_code', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

/**
 *  Prints the box content
 */
function post_options_code( $post ) { 
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), $post->post_type . '_noncename' );
    $meta_info = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_meta_info', true) ? get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_meta_info', true) : 1; ?>
    <h2><?php _e( 'Meta Information' ); ?></h2>
    <div class="alignleft">
        <input id="meta_default" type="radio" name="_meta_info" value="meta_default"<?php checked( 'meta_default', $meta_info ); ?><?php echo ( $meta_info == 1 )?' checked="checked"' : ''; ?> /> <label for="meta_default" class="selectit"><?php _e( 'Use default post setting' ); ?></label><br />
        <input id="show_meta" type="radio" name="_meta_info" value="show_meta"<?php checked( 'show_meta', $meta_info ); ?> /> <label for="show_meta" class="selectit"><?php _e( 'Show meta info' ); ?></label><br />
        <input id="hide_meta" type="radio" name="_meta_info" value="hide_meta"<?php checked( 'hide_meta', $meta_info ); ?> /> <label for="hide_meta" class="selectit"><?php _e( 'Hide meta info' ); ?></label><br />
    </div>
    <div class="alignright">
        <span class="description"><?php _e( 'Your explanation here' ); ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <hr /><?php
}

/** 
 * When the post is saved, saves our custom data 
 */
function save_post_options( $post_id ) {
  // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
      return;

  // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
  // because save_post can be triggered at other times
  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( @$_POST[$_POST['post_type'] . '_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
      return;

  // Check permissions
  if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
     return;

  // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
  if( 'post' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
      if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
          return;
      } else {
          update_post_meta( $post_id, '_meta_info', $_POST['_meta_info'] );
      }
  } 

}
```